# HTML: Uniform Cell Size When Spanning

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need some help with my HTML layout.
I am trying to make a simple calculator number pad.
I'd like my "=" button to be larger, so I used a `rowspan` to stretch it across two rows.
However, (in Chrome) this seems to make my last two rows bigger than the first two.
I have tried setting my cell padding/spacing to zero, but I get the same effect.

**Update:**
Since no one has answered yet...

I have been reading and it looks like there is a consensus to not use `table`s for layout purposes.  With that, what *are* you supposed to use? I found tons of material explaining why tables are so bad, but very little about how to make a table/grid layout without them. Would it be better to do this using something other than `table`?

**/Update**

Here is the HTML (I am planning to apply CSS later):

```
<html>
    <div>
        <table width="200" height="300" border="0" style="table-layout:fixed">
            <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><input type="text" style="width:100%; text-align:right" value="0" readonly /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input type="button" style="width:100%;height:100%" value="7" /></td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input type="button" style="width:100%;height:100%" value="8" /></td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input type="button" style="width:100%;height:100%" value="9" /></td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input type="button" style="width:100%;height:100%" value="-" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input type="button" style="width:100%;height:100%" value="4" /></td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input type="button" style="width:100%;height:100%" value="5" /></td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input type="button" style="width:100%;height:100%" value="6" /></td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input type="button" style="width:100%;height:100%" value="+" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input type="button" style="width:100%;height:100%" value="1" /></td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input type="button" style="width:100%;height:100%" value="2" /></td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input type="button" style="width:100%;height:100%" value="3" /></td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="2"><input type="button" style="width:100%;height:100%" value="=" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input type="button" style="width:100%;height:100%" value="+/-" /></td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input type="button" style="width:100%;height:100%" value="0"   /></td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input type="button" style="width:100%;height:100%" value="."   /></td>
            <!-- ROWSPAN -->
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</html>
```

The button sizes look fine on FireFox.
As an aside: Does anyone know why IE9 contorts the buttons into weird sizes?

Here is an image, see the bottom two rows are slightly larger:

[image]

Comment: Just responding to your table conversation... it's recommended to use a block container such as div; or section, article, aside, etc for layout. At least in what I've been taught, you should reserve tables for tabular data only. I think it's fine for a calculator like this though.

Answer (score 1):

The approach is too complicated. It is better to set the sizes of the `input` elements (the buttons) and let the browser allocate the sizes of cells accordingly. The following style sheet illustrates a simpler approach. It looks a bit complicated since it has to override some settings that you now have in HTML attributes. It is generally best to do styling consistently in external style sheets or at least in a `style` element. If you simplify the markup, you can reduce the style sheet as well.

```
table, td { height: auto !important; width: auto !important; }
td { width: 2em; height: 2em; padding: 0;}
input { padding: 0; font-size: 100%;
        width: 2em !important; height: 2em !important; }
td[rowspan="2"] input { height: 4em !important; }
td[colspan="4"] input { width: 8em !important; }
```